# In Joshua 6:6, do the seven priests carrying trumpets in front of the Ark represent the seven angels carrying trumpets in front of Jesus on his Day?

Tags: revelation, joshua, angels, 1-enoch, ark-of-the-covenant

Joshua 6:6

> So Joshua the son of Nun called the priests and said to them, “Take up
> the Ark of the Covenant and let **seven priests bear seven trumpets** of
> rams’ horns **in front of the Ark of YHWH**.”

Revelation 8:6

> Then the **seven angels who had the seven trumpets** prepared to sound
> them.

Revelation 11:19

> Then the temple of God in heaven was opened, and **the Ark of His
> Covenant appeared** in His temple. And there were flashes of lightning,
> and rumblings, and peals of thunder, and an earthquake, and a great
> hailstorm.

1 Thessalonians 4:16

> For **the Lord** Himself will descend from heaven with a loud command,
> with the voice of **an archangel**, and with **the trumpet of God**, and
> the dead in Christ will be the first to rise.

1 Enoch 20:1–8

> And these are the names of the holy angels who watch:
>
> **Uriel**, one of the holy angels, who is over the world and over Tartarus.
>
> **Raphael**, one of the holy angels, who is over the spirits of men.
>
> **Raguel**, one of the holy angels who takes vengeance on the world of the luminaries.
>
> **Michael**, one of the holy angels, who is set over the best
> part of mankind and over chaos.
>
> **Saraqael**, one of the holy angels, who is set over the spirits, who sin in the spirit.
>
> **Gabriel**, one of the holy angels, who is over Paradise and the serpents and the Cherubim.
>
> **Remiel**, one of the holy angels, whom God set over those who rise.

Comment: There is no connection whatsoever between the fall of Jericho and seven archangels.

Comment: There is a connection because priesthood started in the old testament and continued with Jesus Christ who is High Priest intercepting on our own behalf

Comment: It's just that the earlier was on earth with the Israelites and the later is in heaven. Remember Christians will be priests before God forever

Comment: @DongLi, so do the seven priests with trumpets represent the seven archangels with trumpets before Christ to resurrect the saints on the Day of the Lord?

Comment: Yes they do because the priests received instructions from God who was setting a similar priesthood setup here like that which is in heaven, remember there is an altar in heaven like there was an altar on earth. There is a priest in heaven and there is a priest here on earth so the priests represent the angels

Comment: Yeah it's all related, there is no co-incidenc e

Comment: Yes, but what has any of this to do with archangels???

Comment: @DongLi That's what I was thinking too. The 7 angels are the 7 priests, both with trumpets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The priesthood already existed in heaven, even before God gave Moses the instructions on how to setup the ark of the covenant. So yes, the seven priests are a parallel to the seven angels carrying trumpets before the High Priest Jesus Christ.

The Book of Revelation tells us that Jesus is dressed in a breastplate clothing like the priests in the Old Testament did. So the ark of the covenant here on earth was a parallel to the ark of the covenant in heaven. The priests represent the angelic witnesses carrying trumpets in front of Jesus on the coming Day of Christ.

Comment: "The priests represent the angelic witnesses carrying trumpets in front of Jesus." -Dong Li

Comment: Exactly, God replicating the priesthood setup in heaven on earth